# Is Cleric actually Tyrant?

Tags: dont-tell-my-parents

In *Please Don't Tell My Parents I Work For A Supervillain*, Cleric is (supposedly) a chief minion of the supervillain Tyrant, who has tried to conquer the world three times. Magenta's belief is that Cleric is infatuated with Tyrant, which seems to be confirmed when she enters his room and sees pictures of Tyrant all over his room, which incidentally seems to confirm that she knows what Tyrant looks like, and that he does not look like Cleric.

However, there is a very notable clue that suggests that Cleric could *be* Tyrant. When he takes control of some blank pieces of paper in a battle (something that he had previously denied being able to do), the word "Tyrant" appears on every piece of paper. It would seem strange for him to be prioritizing writing the name of his boss on paper in the heat of battle—but it would make a lot of sense if *his* name appeared on paper that he was controlling. For that matter, the plot at the end of the book was supposed to be Tyrant's masterstroke, and he not only seemingly is not personally present to oversee his brave new world, but as far we see *never contacts Cleric* about this seemingly important project.

Moreoever, Tyrant's appearance is also conspicuously never described, even when images of him are present, and the whole story is about someone with a power to not be recognized or alter their appearance, with at least two other people with similar powers (Claire Lutra and Retcon) seen as well. Cleric also seems suspiciously familiar with the sort of powers that might let someone pass undetected....

Is there any confirmation that Cleric is (or is not) Tyrant?

Comment: I [sent this on to the author](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1516751040133181443?t=fBCK-EXeWCMbqT74mUi5Ow&s=19), who has been responsive in the past. Fascinating question...

Comment: ^_^ Incidentally, great to see a fellow reader of the series! I love these books.

Comment: @Adamant - Given how responsive the author is, you might want to have a good think about any other questions you want answering while they're paying out :-)

Comment: ^_^ I mentioned that this might lead to more questions, and he said he's happy to have more, although he reserves the right to not answer some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently not](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1516751040133181443?t=fBCK-EXeWCMbqT74mUi5Ow&s=19).

> I love people coming up with theories like this.  I LOVE it.  I must dash this one.  Cleric is not Tyrant.  I will try to answer the arguments included:
>
> Having the ability to stamps Tyrant on the pages is natural.  I’m not going to confirm if it’s part of Cleric’s inherent powers or some device he carries, but he is fanatically devoted to Tyrant.  He would rather put Tyrant than himself on anything.
>
> This is not Tyrant’s master stroke!  This is a major plan by one of Tyrant’s top minions, who works independently.  Tyrant trusts Cleric and Cleric’s competence.  I think Cleric deserves it.  Cleric pulled out all the stops on this one, but Tyrant has many big plans.
>
> Again, Cleric has the rare honor of developing, planning, and running plans entirely in his own.  Tyrant trusts Cleric, and Cleric is in charge of finding peaceful, creative ways to bring change.  Cleric has a lot of authority, but is also the entire ‘peaceful’ branch by himself.
>
> Good catch that I was vague on Tyrant’s looks.  Wrong reason, but good catch.
>
> Retcon does not have mind control powers.  Retcon’s power is far worse, and exactly what the name sounds like.  Retcon alters the past.  Scary?  Very.  But what are the limits?  Retcon will never tell.
>
> I am surprised and delighted that anyone is out there posting online about my books.  Fan theories, no less.  I hide a LOT of stuff in the background of my books.  They are thick with detail the main character barely notices or misunderstands.  I’m afraid this is not one of them!
>
> Have I covered everything?

[image: Richard Roberts's reply]