# Why is Tyrant's appearance described in vague terms?

Tags: dont-tell-my-parents

In *Please Don't Tell My Parents I Work for a Supervillain*, the text is suspiciously taciturn about what Tyrant looks like, even when people who recognize him are looking at photos of him. As noted in the [answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262367/51379), the author of the *Please Don't Tell My Parents* series has indicated that there is a plot-related reason for the vague description of Tyrant's appearance:

> Good catch that I was vague on Tyrant’s looks. Wrong reason, but good catch.

The author has also quashed the idea that this is because Cleric is really Tyrant. As such, that naturally leads to the question: why *is* Tyrant's appearance described in such vague terms?